# Two different matrices for affine transformations

Tags: javascript, matrix

I recently encountered two different matrix implementations for 2d affine transformations in javascript. They produce different results with the same set of transformations and I was wondering why one is used over the other, why is there 2 different ones and why they produce different results when affine transformations should be a universally defined and simple concept?

The first I encountered in here:
https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix
and boils down to:

```
multiply(factor){
      let result = Mat3.identity();
      let a0 = factor.data[0][0],
        a1 = factor.data[1][0],
        a2 = factor.data[0][1],
        a3 = factor.data[1][1],
        a4 =factor.data[0][2],
        a5 = factor.data[1][2];
      let b0 = this.data[0][0],
        b1 = this.data[1][0],
        b2 = this.data[0][1],
        b3 = this.data[1][1],
        b4 = this.data[0][2],
        b5 = this.data[1][2];
      result.data[0][0] = a0 * b0 + a2 * b1;
      result.data[1][0] = a1 * b0 + a3 * b1;
      result.data[0][1] = a0 * b2 + a2 * b3;
      result.data[1][1] = a1 * b2 + a3 * b3;
      result.data[0][2] = a0 * b4 + a2 * b5 + a4;
      result.data[1][2] = a1 * b4 + a3 * b5 + a5;
      return result;
}
```

for matrix by matrix multiplication. It is a 3x2 matrix.
the second one has the same behaviour as the html canvas transformation matrix and is a 3x3 matrix

```
multiply(factor){
   let result = Mat3.identity();
   for(let i = 0;i<3;i++){
        for(let j = 0; j <3;j++){
          let oneResult = 0;
          for(let o = 0; o<3;o++){
            oneResult += this.data[i][o]*factor.data[o][j];
          }
          result.data[i][j] = oneResult;
        }
      }
      return result;
}
```

they are not equivalent. The first one has the distinction of providing zoom-on-a-point with translate(point)*scale(zoom)*translate(-point). While the second one requires a different algorithm(I am also curious as to what kind of transformation could provide such functionality on the second one).